# How can I fix this problem? It annoying me long time

Tags: visual-studio

The window never show up clearly and complete. The Picture is below

[Screen Show for Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntMad.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, Changed my monitor dpi from 300 to 150